# regex for a string ,\"16 questions\",

Tags: regex

I am not good in regex and I spent so much time figure out how to search for the below pattern:

```
,\"16 questions\",
```

This is what I constructed `.\"[0-9,]+ questions\".`
I think I am close but not sure how much. Can someone please correct it. The numeric value can have comma in it when the number crosses 1k. e.g 2,500 questions.

Comment: Does your pattern actually fail you?  Is the input from an untrustworthy source that you need to strictly validate it?  What language are you coding in?  What is your goal with this task?  Extract the number?  Replace text? Validate the string?

Answer (score 3):

```
,"\d{1,3}(,\d{3,3})*\squestions?",
```

Explanation:

- `\d{1,3}`= 1~3 decimal digits
- `(,\d{3,3})*` = comma and 3 decimal digits, the whole group repeating 0~N times
- `\s` = whitespace
- `s?` = letter `s` can be missing

These two parts give you accurate recognition of possible numbers.

▶ [Test and visualization.](https://www.debuggex.com/r/rydAte6Sx4-yLTcK)

If the backslashes in your text are true backslashes, then the regex including them would be

```
,\\"\d{1,3}(,\d{3,3})*\squestions?\\",
```

Comment: regex breaks on `21,3133 questions` shouldn't accept.

Comment: @shockawave123 – pardon me, I am not sure what you want to say, you sentence does not give me grammatical sense. And what is "regex breaking"? `21,3333` is not matched by this regex and that is correct.

Comment: Your regular expression accepts the strings that are not numbers.  got to the link for an example. https://regex101.com/r/ZyQIdh/1

Comment: @shockawave123 – but what you gave as an example is not my regex. The OP's request for regex was different, see the question.

Answer (score 0):

This works. You didn't indicate if the numeric value could have more than 1 comma (e.g. 1,000,000)

```
,\\"((\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*)\squestions?\\",
```

Comment: This matches `,"1,2,3,4,5,6 question"`